# every other letter in hashmap putting

Tags: java

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hm1 = new HashMap<String,Integer>
HashMap<String,Integer> hm2 = new HashMap<String,Integer>
```

I am looking to loop through an alphabet and add 'a-z' matching with numbers based on their occurrence in a text. I have this fully working however I am now changing this up. I want it to go through two hashmaps e.g. 'a' goes to hm1, 'b' goes to hm2, 'c' goes to hm1. 'd' goes to hm2. So every other one changes. I've been trying to do it for around a couple hours now and struggling.

I'm trying to do it by accessing the index of the value and trying to do modulo so if it's e.g. 0-25 then only doing then adding the even number index to one hashmap and the odd to the other. this way I would get every other letter as desired. However cannot seem to get this working, very frustrating!

EDIT:
example:

```
  for ( char a = 'a'; a < z; a++){
    for ( int i = 0; 0<25; i++){
         h1.put(a,i);
          }
       }
```

if I wanted the above to do this but instead of all being in one hashmap, over two hashmaps so one doing a,c,e and the other doing b,d,f and so on... but with the values not being so obvious 0-25 but potentially large numbers.

Comment: what is your actual goal? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing

Comment: My goal is to make it possible for looping through one set of things and being able to rotate so one loop it adds to hm1 the next to hm2 then hm1 then hm2 ect... @SeanPatrickFloyd

Comment: slightly edited it to give you more of an informative insight @VivekSingh

Comment: `for (int i=0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {i%2 == 0 ? hm1.put(...) : hm2.put(...);}`

Comment: @MickMnemonic What about in the case where I'm spreading it through multiple hashmaps, this scenario wouldn't work ?

Comment: If you have multiple maps, you can have them in an array and lookup the map with index `i % size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first letter of of the key, get its int value (remember that in java, a character is a int value), and gets its modulo 2. Something like this:

```
private void putValue(String key, Integer value) {
      int firstLetterInt = (int) key.charAt(0);
      if (firstLetterInt % 2 == 0) {
          hm1.put(key, value);
      }
      else {
          hm2.put(key, value);
      }
 }
```

...

```
putValue("a", 66);
putValue("b", 100);
```

A more general case would be to have a list of Maps:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> maps;
```

Providing the map is properly initialized, your `putValue` would look like:

```
private void putValue(String key, Integer value) {
      int firstLetterInt = (int) key.charAt(0);
      maps.get(firstLetterInt % maps.size()).put(key, value);
 }
```

Comment: What about in the case where I'm spreading it through multiple hashmaps, this scenario wouldn't work ?

Comment: You could have a list of Maps, of any size. Then with the modulo operator you could decide to which Map any value should be put.

Comment: I don't understand   maps.get(firstLetterInt % maps.size()).put(key, value); ...... can you please explain this to me

Comment: Assuming there are N maps (that is, a list of maps of size N), firstLetterInt % maps.size() gives a number between 0 and the N - 1, so we know in which of the N maps we should put the value.

Answer (score 1):

The double loop doesn't do what you think it does.
For every value of a, you are executing the inner loop 25 times, which causes you to put every character as value 25. Instead of the inner loop, you should have a counter variable that is initialized outside the char loop and incremented inside it.